# Executing an Unknown Action always synchronously

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am currently working on a simulation class library that will be used by other programmers to create a dynamic simulation timeline and run these simulations.

In a sense, this is done by letting the user of the library specify actions on certain points in simulated time.

But I am now running into problems where an action that has been created by the user can be either async or not. To keep the simulation consistent though I need to execute both variants synchronously. I boiled the problem down to a very simple example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Action action = ActionFromUser();

        action();

        Console.WriteLine("2");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static Action ActionFromUser()
    {
        Random rng = new Random();

        if (rng.Next(0, 2) == 0) // 50/50
        {
            return async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("1");
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("1");
            };
        }

    }
}
```

The problem now comes down to that the output is dependent on whether the action is async or sync which is the behavior I want to get rid of.

The action will always be without parameters and without a return value.

I do **not** want to use reflection (`action.Method.IsDefined(typeof(AsyncStateMachineAttribute), ...`).

I tried switching from `Action` to `delegate` (`Func` does not seem to be a good option since I have to specify a return value type) but I haven't found anything there that would help me.

Comment: You will have to change your `ActionFromUser` and your api to always require async tasks, and then the implementor of the methods that return them will have to choose whether to use async code or not. `Action` does not allow you to wait for the tasks used inside unless the code wrapped in the `Action` actually wait for it. You can't return an async delegate out through an `Action` delegate, you lose the part that handles the continuation.

Comment: The question is if you really want to go down this route. Isn't it much better to just document that all `Action` delegates returned will be executed synchronously (aka "normally"), and any abuse by the developer to internally spawn sub-tasks that nobody waits for is just a bug **on their part**?

Comment: An *async lambda* on an `Action`, is an `async void`. Its highly unlikely you'd want this . If in doubt change it to a `Func<Task>` and return a *completed task* on *synchronous* result, and `await`

Comment: As others have said, the `Action` constructor doesn't understand async delegates. The C# language allows [async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) methods for very specific reasons, that most probably are not applicable in your case.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. After trying out the different suggestions and doing some refactoring I think I will stick to the `Func<Task>` solution as it fits really good so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *async lambda* on an `Action`, is an `async void`. It's highly unlikely you'd want this . If in doubt change it to a `Func<Task>` and return a *completed task* on the  *synchronous* result, and `await` the results.

Note : this is a contrived example, I'd imagine your code is a lot different, however it illustrates the point:

```
static Func<Task> FromUserAsync()
{
    Random rng = new Random();

    if (rng.Next(0, 2) == 0) // 50/50
    {
        return async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("1");
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return () =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    }

}
```

One last note, you should probably catch any exceptions in the synchronous path and place them on the task, with `Task.FromException`